# call xml file in wallpaperservice?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, live-wallpaper

I would like to create a google map in live wallpaper. To create mapview xml file is needed to initialize the layout. But there is no way to call xml file in wallpaperservice that I know from the previous discussion. Please let me know if anybody get knowledge about this topics and also help me if there is another way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define it in wallpaperservice xml file.

If you have a surfaceView/GlsurfaceView, you just need to inflate the layout in your view

wallpaper service only provides you the service and since it is a service you can't use layouts..

Comment: please say something with the illustration.